How to retrieve a task's progress as percentage done in Dask?
I'd like to query for a task's status in a Dask cluster by retrieving a percentage completed beyond the visual progress bar or dashboard. For example, I'm submitting this task below:
from dask.distributed import Client

def my_task(x):
    import time
    time.sleep(5)
    return x ** 2

client = Client()
future = client.submit(my_task, 10, key="my_task_0")

I can get the status which is returned as a category such as "pending", "running", "finished.": print(future.status) 
I know this progress bar can visually print the progress of the task:
from dask.distributed import progress
progress(future)

How can I retrieve the percentage completed from that progress bar as numbers?



Do you want the percentage of tasks finished? I thought perhaps you meant the percent progress within tasks, which is not possible.

@mdurant I thought the percent progress for a single task would be possible, but good to know. How can we retrieve the percentage of tasks finished?

The text version includes the percentage: progress(future, notebook=False). Since you only have one future, this will go from 0% to 100% with nothing in-between.
